# mstest - /resultsfile doesnt work when /testsettings switch is used

Tags: mstest

I need to specify the location of the MSTest log file.  I was doing this just fine with /resultfile:path but we needed the global timout, etc from the .settings file so i added the /testsettings:testfile.testsettings switch.  Now that ive done that, MSTest no longer creates the log.

Any ideas?  Ive tried specifying /resultfile switch after /testsettings

Comment: Are you sure your tests actually still get performed after changing the commandline?

Comment: @kroonwijk - yes the tests do still run but no log file is generated.

Comment: Can you try to use ProcessMonitor from MS Sysinternal toolsuite to see if there is any attempt even to start generation of such a file? And can you publish the content of your testsettings xml here, so we can take a look at what it might overrule?